# What are your LS_COLORS?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

After installing a full version of Cygwin, I open up the MinTTY shell and I like the green on black.  However, when I do an 'ls', I get a dark blue for directories.  It's not very readable.  I found that the [LS_COLORS environment variable](http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html) controls the output of ls.  Here is my current default:

```
no=00:fi=00:di=00;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=00;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:
or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=00;32:
*.com=00;32:*.btm=00;32:*.bat=00;32:*.sh=00;32:*.csh=00;32:*.tar=00;31:
*.tgz=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.z=00;31:
*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.bz=00;31:*.tz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:
*.cpio=00;31:*.jpg=00;35:*.gif=00;35:*.bmp=00;35:*.xbm=00;35:*.xpm=00;35:
*.png=00;35:*.tif=00;35:
```

Changing from `di=00;34` to `di=00;94` makes ls much more readable.  Has anyone found other useful tweaks?

Comment: I believe this is appropriate under Superuser. See my similar question at [Colorizing your terminal and shell environment?](http://superuser.com/questions/146182/colorizing-your-terminal-and-shell-environment)

Answer (score 21):

For readability purposes, instead of changing the colors that LS_COLORS produces, it's smarter to change how your terminal interprets those colors by mapping "dark blue" to a more readable RGB value. If dark blue is unreadable for you in `ls`, it's going to be unreadable for you everywhere.

Generally, the main time you should change `LS_COLORS` is whenever you want `ls` to know about other extensions or to treat them separately.

Comment: Interesting idea.  How would one re-map "dark blue"?

Comment: It depends on your terminal -- this is usually configurable. For instance, in `gnome-terminal`, it's in `Edit > Profiles > Colors`.

Comment: Nice suggestion! This also works in PuTTY.
Open the settings menu, click Window->Colours and use the "Select colour to adjust" options to redefine the RGB value of "ANSI Blue".
(don't forget to save the default settings under the session menu, or these settings won't stick)

Answer (score 0):

I always just switch background to white and main text to black, for that very reason.

(I'm not a Cygwin user so I'm just referring to terminal sessions generally)

I never understood the preference for dark backgrounds..

hth

Comment: That's funny, I never understood the preference for bright backgrounds.  I guess it's just "creative difference".

Comment: hehe, the bright background works quite well on this website, don't you think ;)

Comment: It works, but I wonder how much easier on the eyes a black background would be ;)  Too bad there's not an easy fix like LS_COLORS for websites.