# How do I get rid of this really ugly highlighting on iterm?

Tags: iterm2

[image]

i have no idea where this highlighting came from, I remember installing a bunch of different things to jazz up my terminal but not sure what caused this, and have no idea where to even look for it.

Comment: Maybe this is what you have used. https://medium.com/@Clovis_app/configuration-of-a-beautiful-efficient-terminal-and-prompt-on-osx-in-7-minutes-827c29391961

Answer (score 0):

Something is setting the LS_COLORS environment variable to enable that coloring in that way. That, or you have a .dir_colors hidden file at the your user's home folder.

References:

- [dir_colors man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/dir_colors.5.html)
- [Rather popular github repo with better colors](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS)

Related: [What are your LS_COLORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085834/what-are-your-ls-colors)